# Optapy domain definitions help. Getting error: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack

Tags: python, java, optaplanner, optapy

I am trying to write a pilot rostering project, where pilots and copilots need to be assigned to flights ("Duty"). I'm using python because there are existing python investments at the client.

I'm basing this POC off of the [optapy Employee Scheduling quickstart.](https://github.com/optapy/optapy-quickstarts/tree/stable/employee-scheduling)

The code is crashing in my `domain.py`, while trying to init my Availability class.
Specifically, in the `@optapy.problem_fact` decorator wrapping it. `optapy\annotations.py, line 585`

```
File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PythonClassTranslator.java", line 292, in org.optaplanner.jpyinterpreter.PythonClassTranslator.translatePythonClass
Exception: Java Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\jpyinterpreter\python_to_java_bytecode_translator.py", line 1220, in translate_python_class_to_java_class
    out = PythonClassTranslator.translatePythonClass(python_compiled_class)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\jpyinterpreter\python_to_java_bytecode_translator.py", line 422, in convert_to_java_python_like_object
    out = translate_python_class_to_java_class(raw_type)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\jpyinterpreter\python_to_java_bytecode_translator.py", line 399, in convert_to_java_python_like_object
    convert_to_java_python_like_object(map_value, instance_map))
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\jpyinterpreter\python_to_java_bytecode_translator.py", line 1193, in translate_python_class_to_java_class
    static_attributes_map.put(attribute[0], convert_to_java_python_like_object(attribute[1]))
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\optapy\optaplanner_java_interop.py", line 1050, in compile_and_get_class
    parent_class = translate_python_class_to_java_class(python_class).getJavaClass()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\optapy\optaplanner_java_interop.py", line 1063, in _generate_problem_fact_class
    parent_class = compile_and_get_class(python_class)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\optapy\annotations.py", line 585, in problem_fact
    out.__optapy_java_class = _generate_problem_fact_class(fact_class)
  File "C:\Users\andre\Desktop\Pilot Rosterer 3000\domain.py", line 131, in <module>
    class Availability:
```

The error is as following:

```
Exception has occurred: java.lang.VerifyError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/jpyinterpreter/user/enum/Enum/__new__$$2.invoke(Lorg/jpyinterpreter/user/domain/AvailabilityType;Lorg/optaplanner/jpyinterpreter/PythonLikeObject;)Lorg/optaplanner/jpyinterpreter/PythonLikeObject; @897: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'org/optaplanner/jpyinterpreter/PythonLikeObject' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/optaplanner/jpyinterpreter/types/PythonLikeType'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @897
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/jpyinterpreter/user/enum/Enum/__new__$$2', 'org/jpyinterpreter/user/domain/AvailabilityType', 'org/optaplanner/jpyinterpreter/PythonLikeObject', 'org/jpyinterpreter/user/domain/AvailabilityType', 'org/optaplanner/jpyinterpreter/PythonLikeObject', top, 'org/optaplanner/jpyinterpreter/types/PythonNone', top, top, top, null, 'org/optaplanner/jpyinterpreter/types/collections/PythonLikeTuple', top, top, top, top, top, 'java/lang/Object', 'org/optaplanner/jpyinterpreter/PythonLikeObject' }
    stack: { 'org/optaplanner/jpyinterpreter/PythonLikeObject', 'org/optaplanner/jpyinterpreter/PythonLikeObject', 'org/optaplanner/jpyinterpreter/PythonLikeObject' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b200 5a3a 0b2b 4e2c 3a04 2ac0 0002 b400
    ... ... ...
```

domain.py

```
import optapy
import optapy.types
import optapy.score
import datetime
import enum

class Route:
    name: str
    duration: int
    base: str

    def __init__(self, name: str = None, duration: int = None, base: str = None):
        self.name = name
        self.duration = duration
        self.base = base

class AvailabilityType(enum.Enum):
    DESIRED = 'DESIRED'
    UNDESIRED = 'UNDESIRED'
    UNAVAILABLE = 'UNAVAILABLE'

    @staticmethod
    def list():
        return list(map(lambda at: at, AvailabilityType))


@optapy.problem_fact
class Pilot:
    name: str
    skill_set: list[str]
    home_base: str
    duties: list # list[Duty]

    def __init__(self, name: str = None, skill_set: list[str] = None, home_base: str = None, duties: list = None):
        self.name = name
        self.skill_set = skill_set
        self.home_base = home_base
        if duties is None:
            self.duties = []
        else:
            self.duties = duties

    def get_total_hours(self): # flight hours
        dt = datetime.timedelta()
        for duty in self.duties:
            if duty.work_type != "Flying": continue # skip non-flight duties
            dt += duty.end - duty.start
        return dt.seconds/3600 + dt.days*24

    def get_todays_hours(self, date: datetime.date):
        dt = datetime.timedelta()
        for duty in self.duties:
            if duty.work_type != "Flying": continue # skip non-flight duties
            if duty.start.date() != date: continue # skip duties from other days
            dt += duty.end - duty.start         # not taking into account flights over midnight. TODO: fix
        return dt.seconds/3600 + dt.days*24

    def get_total_overtime_hours(self):
        days = dict()
        for duty in self.duties:
            if duty.work_type != "Flying": continue # skip non-flight duties
            day = duty.start.date()
            days[day] = days.get(day, datetime.timedelta()) + duty.end - duty.start

        total_overtime = datetime.timedelta()
        MAX_FLIGHT_HOURS_ALLOWED = datetime.timedelta(hours=10)
        for day in days:
            if day > MAX_FLIGHT_HOURS_ALLOWED:
                total_overtime += day - MAX_FLIGHT_HOURS_ALLOWED
        return total_overtime.seconds/3600 + total_overtime.days*24

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Pilot(name={self.name})'

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'skill_set': self.skill_set,
            'home_base': self.home_base,
            'duties': self.duties
        }


def duty_pinning_filter(solution, duty):
    return not solution.schedule_state.is_draft(duty)


@optapy.planning_entity(pinning_filter=duty_pinning_filter)
@optapy.planning_pin
class Duty:
    id: int
    start: datetime.datetime
    end: datetime.datetime
    work_type: str
    detail: str
    required_skill: str
    pilot: Pilot
    # coPilot: Pilot # REMOVED: No longer complicating duties with 2 pilots, rather just creating seperate pilot duties and copilot duties for each route. This allows us to model duties other than flights
    bases: list[str] # locaiotn(s) from which the duty can be performed

    def __init__(self, id: int = None, start: datetime.datetime = None, end: datetime.datetime = None, work_type: str = None, detail: str = None, required_skill: str = None, pilot: Pilot = None, bases: list[str] = None):
        self.id = id
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.work_type = work_type
        self.detail = detail
        self.required_skill = required_skill
        self.pilot = pilot
        self.bases = bases

    @optapy.planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Duty:{self.id}\t | {self.work_type}, detail={self.detail}, pilot={self.pilot}, start={self.start}, end={self.end}, required_skill={self.required_skill}, bases={self.bases})'

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'work_type': self.work_type,
            'start': self.start.isoformat(),
            'end': self.end.isoformat(),
            'detail': self.detail,
            'required_skill': self.required_skill,
            'pilot': self.pilot.to_dict() if self.pilot is not None else None,
            'bases': self.bases
        }

# ============================================================================================
# This is to get around the circular reference problem.
# The optapy decorators cannot refence Duty/Pilot before the classes are instantiated,
# but the classes rely on eachother being instantiated first before they can instatiated
# themselves. Hence the circular reference issue.
@optapy.planning_list_variable(Duty, ['duties_list'])
def get_duties(self):
    return self.duties

def set_duties(self, duties):
    self.duties = duties

@optapy.planning_variable(Pilot, value_range_provider_refs=['pilot_range'])
def get_pilot(self):
    return self.pilot

def set_pilot(self, pilot):
    self.pilot = pilot

Pilot.get_duties = get_duties
Pilot.set_duties = set_duties

Duty.get_pilot = get_pilot
Duty.set_pilot = set_pilot
# ============================================================================================

@optapy.problem_fact
class Availability:
    pilot: Pilot
    date: datetime.date
    availability_type: AvailabilityType

    def __init__(self, pilot: Pilot = None, date: datetime.date = None, availability_type: AvailabilityType = None):
        self.pilot = pilot
        self.date = date
        self.availability_type = availability_type

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Availability(pilot={self.pilot}, date={self.date}, availability_type={self.availability_type})'

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'pilot': self.pilot.to_dict(),
            'date': self.date.isoformat(),
            'availability_type': self.availability_type.value
        }


class ScheduleState:
    publish_length: int
    draft_length: int
    first_draft_date: datetime.date
    last_historic_date: datetime.date

    def __init__(self, publish_length: int = None, draft_length: int = None, first_draft_date: datetime.date = None, last_historic_date: datetime.date = None):
        self.publish_length = publish_length
        self.draft_length = draft_length
        self.first_draft_date = first_draft_date
        self.last_historic_date = last_historic_date

    def is_draft(self, duty):
        return duty.start >= datetime.datetime.combine(self.first_draft_date, datetime.time.min)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'publish_length': self.publish_length,
            'draft_length': self.draft_length,
            'first_draft_date': self.first_draft_date.isoformat(),
            'last_historic_date': self.last_historic_date.isoformat()
        }


@optapy.planning_solution
class PilotSchedule:
    schedule_state: ScheduleState
    availability_list: list[Availability]
    pilot_list: list[Pilot]
    duty_list: list[Duty]
    solver_status: optapy.types.SolverStatus
    score: optapy.score.SimpleScore

    def __init__(self, schedule_state, availability_list, pilot_list, duty_list, solver_status, score=None):
        self.pilot_list = pilot_list
        self.availability_list = availability_list
        self.schedule_state = schedule_state
        self.duty_list = duty_list
        self.solver_status = solver_status
        self.score = score

    @optapy.problem_fact_collection_property(Pilot)
    @optapy.value_range_provider('pilot_range')
    def get_pilot_list(self):
        return self.pilot_list

    @optapy.problem_fact_collection_property(Availability)
    def get_availability_list(self):
        return self.availability_list

    @optapy.planning_entity_collection_property(Duty)
    def get_duty_list(self):
        return self.duty_list

    @optapy.planning_score(optapy.score.HardSoftScore)
    def get_score(self):
        return self.score

    def set_score(self, score):
        self.score = score

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'pilot_list': list(map(lambda pilot: pilot.to_dict(), self.pilot_list)),
            'availability_list': list(map(lambda availability: availability.to_dict(), self.availability_list)),
            'schedule_state': self.schedule_state.to_dict(),
            'duty_list': list(map(lambda duty: duty.to_dict(), self.duty_list)),
            'solver_status': self.solver_status.toString(),
            'score': self.score.toString(),
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with OptaPy (see https://github.com/optapy/optapy/issues/146). In particular, it seems to be caused when translating an `enum.Enum` class (which is caused because Availability has type annotation for AvailabilityType, an enum). Removing the type annotation might fix the issue (since then `AvailabilityType` will not be translated until solving, which is more forgiving (since the translation results in an error, it will be translated as a pointer to a `CPython` class)). Will update this answer when the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Updating from Python 3.9.0 to 3.11.1 solved the issue for me.